# How to print an array in a particular triangular shape?

Tags: c, arrays

I have an array of ten elements `{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j}`. I want to print it like this:

```
a  
b e
c f h
d g i j
```

Note that the first column consists of the first four values of my array. The second column (starting in row two) consists of the next three values of the array and so on.

My code is given below

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define size 10

int main() {
  int arr[size] = {14, 22, 34, 57, 44, 42, 33, 55, 48, 47};
  int i, j, n, c, maxTemp;
  n = 4;
  maxTemp = 1;
  c = n - 1;

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = i; j < maxTemp; j = j + c) {
      printf("%d ", arr[j]);
    }
    if (maxTemp <= size) {
      maxTemp = maxTemp + c + 1;
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

For the array

```
int arr[size] = {14, 22, 34, 57, 44, 42, 33, 55, 48, 47};
```

I expected

```
14  
22 44   
34 42 55  
57 33 48 47
```

but got:

```
14  
22 44  
34 42 48   
57 33 47 13
```

Here maybe this is happening because variable `c` value is not decreasing
because I wanted to decrease `c`'s value by one. I've tried but couldn't figure out.

Comment: I think you need to explain how you get from the array to the output.  It is not obvious — though it is roughly that column 1 of the output contains the first 4 values in sequence, column 2 contains the next 3 values, column 3 contains the next 2 values, and column 4 contains the last 1 value.  Does the code have to work with other array sizes — such as a 6-element or 15-element or 21-element array?  What about other sizes, such as 16 or 14 — what is then the expected output?

Comment: Please decribe the logic of your output. Use English to describe how to determine the next number to print. Maybe use their index numbers.

Comment: Actually it was a 4*4 matrix which lower diagonal values were zero.  
1 2 3 4  
0 5 6 7  
0 0 8 9  
0 0 0 10
so the values(axcept zeros) are stored on the given array.  
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] 
so the array size is depend on the matrix size . if 5*5 then size = 15, if 7*7 then size = 28
i need to get back those element column wise by separating the element stored on the given array.@JonathanLeffler

Comment: So you need to print the non zero values of the transpose of a triangular Matrix...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets look at the indexes you want, they are

```
0
1 4
2 5 7
3 6 8 9
```

Fill up the empty spaces with linear numbers (we just not print them later)

```
0 (3  5  6)
1  4 (6  7)
2  5  7 (8)
3  6  8  9
```

The indexes, according to desired pattern rise through the columns.
That gives a linear relation to `i`, i.e. the index will be caculated invovling a `i + ...` part.

Each column (including the fill-in values inside "()") starts with higher value than the last number in the previous column, more or less higher by `n`.
But starting lower (i.e. using some of the values from previous column), in order to match the first empty (filled) rows.
That gives a linear relation to `j*n`, i.e. there will be a `... + j*n`.

Lets try, here are the indexes as `i+j*n`.

```
0 4 8 12
1 5 9 13
2 6 10 14
3 7 11 15
```

These are too high, in each row by 0, 1, 3, 6.
E.g. look at the last row
`3-0==3 7-1==6 11-3==8 15-6==9`

That is `j*(j+1)/2`.
I did not find this myself by the way, so I used my favorite search engine to search for literally "0, 1, 3, 6"; and this popped up:
https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/triangular-numbers.html

Put it together and the correct index is:

```
i+j*n - j*(j+1)/2
```

In code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define size 10

int main(void) {
  int arr[size] = {14, 22, 34, 57, 44, 42, 33, 55, 48, 47};
  int i, j, n=4;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < i+1; j++)
    {
      printf("%d ", i+j*n - j*(j+1)/2 );
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0
1 4
2 5 7
3 6 8 9
```

Comment: if you look at the first artificial row `0 (3 5 6)`: You can write that as `\sum_{i=1}^{c} (n-i)`. From there one can calculate the sum as `n*c - c(c+1)/2`. Then all that is left is to add the current row index.

Comment: Would there be any virtue in modifying the print in the last fragment to something like: `int k = i+j*n - j*(j+1)/2; printf("%d:%d ", k, arr[k]);` and then adjusting the sample output.  This would show both index numbers and the data.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I tried the idea, which seemed quite good at first. But the result looked (purely in my opinion) more confusing. I think that it is clear, that printing array contents instead of indexes gives exactly the desired output described by OP. Valid input nevertheless, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer of Yunnosch is perfectly fine, it involves some not trivial index calculation. In regard of that I propose my solution, which is certainly longer but I believe it is a bit more natural to follow.

Lets consider the example with the letters `array = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j}`. Following the idea that size of the array is triangular number, we can obtain that the number of elements in the longest `column` will be `floor(sqrt(n * 2))` — in our case `floor(sqrt(10 * 2)) = 4`. Once we have that number, it lets us create the following matrix:

```
a b c d
0 e f g
0 0 h i 
0 0 0 j
```

This matrix is easy to make filling it by nested loop using as a limit the number of calculated previously. Once you have this matrix just take the `transpose` of it, and there you have your desired matrix. One may argue that the transposition is itself a complex operation but I think that since it is very well known operation it is easier to spot than calculating the indexes directly.

**Implementation**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int getT(int n){
    int sqr = sqrt(n*2);
    return sqr;
}

int main() {
    char a[10] = {14, 22, 34, 57, 44, 42, 33, 55, 48, 47};
    char b[10][10];

    int limit = getT(10);
    int index1d = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < limit; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < limit; j++){
            if(j < i) b[i][j] = 0;
            else{
                b[i][j] = a[index1d++];
            }
        }
    }
    //transposing by switching the indexes
    for(int i = 0; i < limit; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++){
            printf("%d ",b[j][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```